# Licensing Service in Android App

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have build a free Android App, which is live in Google play store. But some where I have found that License service should get integrated in Android app(compulsary in paid app). Since I am having a free app, so still now I am not using License service in my app. But due to that confusion I am not using new developer console, as when I am migrating from old to new developer console design, I am getting License key for that app. Is it is necessary then to use License Service???????? Please clear my doubts.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You don´t need to use this license for free apps, because everybody can download this file for free and if he´s got roots, there is no cause why the user should not copy this app. The key is created because, if You whish to use it, you can. 
It is even not required to use it for paid apps, that belongs to the developer.